# How does the dummy-pulled cart work?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

Yaichirou has been seen running a cart more than once during the series.
It is pulled by a sort of dummy that runs like crazy, with its legs going back and forth.

[image: The weird magical cart in question, from episode 2]

How exactly does this cart work? Is there any source that explains this?

Also, does it belong to Yaichirou, or the Shimogamo family or is it some sort of 'service' (like a regular taxi)?

Comment: The show has sake-fueled flying teahouses, characters can create physical mazes that interact with the real world, and not just illusions, so I'd say it's magic.